# Remainder of division.

Tags: polynomials

What's the remainder of dividing a polynomial $P(x)=x^{2008}+x^{2007}+1$ with binomial $x^2+1$.

It has to be: $$x^{2008}+x^{2007}+1=(x^2+1)Q(x)+(Ax+B)$$
But when substituting variable $x$ with a constant, that constant also modifies the $Q(x)$ which disables me from obtaining anything useful.

Comment: try with $x=i$.

Comment: Remainder $=2-x$

Comment: Yes, I've done it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p(x) = (x^2\!+1)q(x)\! +\! ax\!+\!b\,\Rightarrow\, p(i) = ai\!+\!b,\ p(-i) = -ai\!+\!b.\,$ Now solve for $\,a,b.$

Answer (score 0):

Write this as

$$x^{2006}(x^2+x+1-1)+1.$$

Then you get

$$x^{2006}(x^2+1)+x^{2006}(x-1)+1\equiv x^{2007}-x^{2006}+1\mod (x^2+1)$$

Proceeding again, we get

$$x^{2005}(x^2-x+1-1)+1\equiv x^{2005}(x^2+1)-x^{2005}(x+1)+1$$

We see that, for $k\ge 2$ we have

> $$x^k+x^{k-1}+1=x^{k-2}(x^2+1)+x^{k-2}(x-1)+1\equiv x^{k-2}(x-1)+1\mod (x^2+1)$$
>   $$x^k-x^{k-1}+1\equiv -x^{k-2}(x+1)+1\mod (x^2+1)$$
>   $$-x^k-x^{k-1}+1\equiv -x^{k-2}(x-1)+1\mod (x^2+1)$$
>   $$-x^k+x^{k-1}+1\equiv x^{k-2}(-x+1)+1\mod (x^2+1).$$

So after 4 applications we see that, for $k\ge 6$ we have

$$x^k+x^{k-1}+1\equiv x^{k-4}+x^{k-5}+1\mod (x^2+1).$$

Which means we can immediately reduce our original problem to

$$x^{2008}+x^{2007}+1\equiv x^4+x^3+1\mod (x^2+1).$$

From there we just use our other reduction formulas to get it down to a linear version which is done after three more applications which lands us in the third case

> $$x^4+x^3+1\equiv -x+2\mod (x^2+1).$$